# Gunicorn doesn't allow requesting urls on the same server instance

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, uwsgi

I'm experiencing a strange problem. I have the following simple/sample Flask application:

```
# from __future__ import print_function
import requests

from flask import Flask

PORT = 6556
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    j = {'data': 1}

    print('INDEX CALLING API')
    response = requests.post('http://localhost:{}/fake_api'.format(PORT), json=j)
    print('INDEX CALLED API')

    return response.text

@app.route('/fake_api', methods=['POST'])
def fake_api():
    print('FAKE_API CALL RECEIVED')
    return 'Ok, it works'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=PORT, debug=True)
```

Basically, what I'm simulating is calling a url (`http://localhost:6556/`) and have the route call with `requests` another url of the same flask app (`http://localhost:6556/fake_api`). Being quite banal, it works fine if I simply start the app with `python server.py`.

The problem is that when I try to run the server with gunicorn like this

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:6556 server:app
```

the application hangs indefinitely on the request. In fact it prints `'INDEX CALLING API'` and then halts.

I've experienced the same problem with uWSGI. Any idea?

**EDIT**

I'm accepting ikkuh's answer since the problem seems linked to a deadlock solvable by spawning multiple processes. However what worked for me is installing and setting `gevent` as worker manager since the default is `sync`:

```
# pip install gevent
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:6556 -k gevent server:app
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like it creates a deadlock when run with gunicorn. It seems to run fine when run with multiple workers as follows:

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:6556 --workers=2 server_test:app
```

This is obviously no real solution as multiple concurrent requests could still create deadlock. I have no clue why this is not happening when run without gunicorn.

Comment: While adding more workers doesn't work adding "-k gevent" (and pip installing gevent, of course) seems to solve the problem. Care to test this to see if it solves the issue also for you? gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:6556 -k gevent server:app

Comment: Might be the case of a single thread calling itself that results in that lock. Having multiple threads helps as well.

Comment: Works with gevent!