# Can’t issue http request from Google App Engine instance (python37/gunicorn) to itself

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-requests, gunicorn

An external Python module that I'm loading as part of my GAE instance can't issue HTTP(s) requests to itself (the same GAE instance) anymore. It always used to work, but recently it stopped working. The outgoing requests (to itself) are timing out. Since it's a third-party module, I can't modify its code, only the URL it uses.

I also tried to access `0.0.0.0:8080`, the port and address that the WSGI app listens to. No success either.

I read about the old Python runtime behaviour to use `urlfetch` or authenticate via HTTP headers, but none of that applies anymore since for the new `python37` runtime, the use of Python's `requests` module is recommended, which I would also like to stick with.

Any idea where to start looking? I seem to have tried everything.

Comment: It would be so helpful knowing the Python version you are using, which is the third party module and a sample of the code you are trying. In my understanding it could be related to a possible deprecation in the module or Python version you are using, as Python2 is deprecated and for what I've found in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/protorpc/wsgi) this library is used with Python2, so in the case you are trying to import this library in your code from Python2 to Python3 you will need to use another library as this one is not supported for App Engine.

Comment: Yes. I did say that I use the `python37` runtime.
The external module is also my own, called typeworld, all pure Python 3 code. The specific line that tries to access the server is here: https://github.com/typeworld/typeworld/blob/e3d09317923cab4d3399eb83a1d7246d51138c5e/Lib/typeworld/client/__init__.py#L287
It's a bit awkward of course that it tries to connect to itself, but that module is not generally meant to run on a server, but rather embedded in a GUI app. I'm just also using it online. You can see my current workaround just above that line: Accessing the main `flask` directly.

Comment: Hello, it will be helpful if you can add any Python code and the stack-trace of the error output you see. What are the reproduction steps that we need to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after much research in another thread: [Gunicorn doesn't allow requesting urls on the same server instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52291784/gunicorn-doesnt-allow-requesting-urls-on-the-same-server-instance)

Because of a deadlock, multiple `gunicorn` workers are needed to be able to connect to self, e.g. `gunicorn -b :8888 -w 2 app:app`.

Having multiple workers on Google App Engine Standard Environment requires an instance class of F2 or higher. You can set the number of workers following your instance class: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#entrypoint_best_practices